# SSRS - multiple toggle in single row item to drill down sub report

Tags: reporting-services

I need to open a sub report using drill down concept. Is there any possible to give toggle for  multiple columns in single row.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WplSn.jpg

The sub report have two parameters to show data. If I click first link the subreport to be drill down with parameters 1 and 5. If I click second link the same sub report to be drill through with different parametrs as 2 and 6.
Any idea to do this?

Comment: It is possible to create your report but have a question .. Can you clarify What values the parameters 1 and 5, and 2 and 6 Are coming from? Is it a dataset fields?

Comment: thats is hard code value to pass parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BIDS 2008, use embedded datasource and dataset as there is a know issue when using shared dataset.

1. Create a Sub Report

In Sub Report, create a parameter, Dataset for your data. Add a table object to your report

You should be able to find lots of examples on how to create your parameter in sub report

Your dataset should use the SubParam1 and SubParam2 in the query for the dataset.

[image]

2. Create your Main Report

Add additional detail line below your data and add your subreports into the column.

[image]

To set your drill down and pass parameter to your sub report, set your sub report property accordingly ..

[image]
[image]

Result .. 1. Three columns, the second and third column not drilled down. 2. Three columns with second column drilled down and third column not drilled down. Separate drill down for column 2 and 3.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. The thing is while expand other both sub report is showing. at a time only one should be visibe

Comment: In the answer, you will see the picture of `Subreport Properties` and `Visibility` in blue. To get to this window, you need to select the sub report in the text box and right mouse click and then select `subreport properties` from the menu. This setting will initially hide the sub report and when you click on drill down it will show.

Comment: In this example, two toggle items are there one is 'Adult' other 'Y'. If I click first one the sub report will expand drill down while click other first should be collapse but for me both is expanding

Comment: There is no way to do what you are asking